# Detect if multiple windows/tracks overlap with a single window using 16bit counter

Tags: c++, algorithm, datetime, bit-manipulation, 64-bit

I am getting Multiple tracks(call it windows) having a start and end timestamp along with a window which has the same. I need to check if any of the tracks timestamp match with this window timestamp. All the timestamps are in 16 bit format. These timestamps are generated from the same monotonic clock.

Process_1:

track_start -> get_data(clock_monotonic) & 0xFFFF

track_end -> get_data(clock_monotonic) & 0xFFFF

Process_2:

window_start -> get_data(clock_monotonic) & 0xFFFF

window_end -> get_data(clock_monotonic) & 0xFFFF

Process_3:

Detect if the tracks match the window?

Problem is rollover with 16bits. Below is my algorithm to fix that:

1. Get current timestamp in 64 bits called 'current'
2. All the timestamps of tracks and window gets transformed as ('current'&0xFFFFFFFFFFFF0000) | timestamp i.e lower 16bits LSB gets replaced by the timestamps.
3. if start > end(rollover problem) we just use the start timestamp and add the difference. So new end timestamp = end + (0xFFFF - start) + end + 1. Look at remap function in the code.
4. This works because Process_3 will get tracks and window timestamps with the maximum of 1minute delay.

   ```
    #include <chrono>
    #include <cstdint>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
    #include <vector>
    #include <time.h>       /* time */
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <assert.h>

    using namespace std;

    auto getTimeStampCount() {
        struct timespec ts;
        clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts );
        return (uint64_t)ts.tv_sec * 1000000000U + (uint64_t)ts.tv_nsec;
    }

    /* returns tuples in this format <16bit start, 16bit end, real 64bit start, real 64bit end> */
    auto generateTimeStamp() {
        auto ms = getTimeStampCount();
        int x = ms & 0xFFFF;
        //generate a random number between 1 and 65535
        int randomNumber = rand() % 65535 + 1;
        int y = (x + randomNumber) & 0xFFFF;/
        return make_tuple(x, y, ms, ms + randomNumber);
    }

    bool isOverlapping(tuple<int64_t, int64_t> a, tuple<int64_t, int64_t> b) {
        return get<0>(a) <= get<1>(b) && get<0>(b) <= get<1>(a);
    }

    //for printing tuples
    template<std::size_t> struct int_{};

    template <class Tuple, size_t Pos>
    std::ostream& print_tuple(std::ostream& out, const Tuple& t, int_<Pos> ) {
        out << std::get< std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value-Pos >(t) << ',';
        return print_tuple(out, t, int_<Pos-1>());
    }

    template <class Tuple>
    std::ostream& print_tuple(std::ostream& out, const Tuple& t, int_<1> ) {
        return out << std::get<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value-1>(t);
    }

    template <class... Args>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const std::tuple<Args...>& t) {
        out << '(';
        print_tuple(out, t, int_<sizeof...(Args)>());
        return out << ')';
    }

    auto remap(int64_t currentTime, tuple<int64_t, int64_t, int64_t, int64_t> t) {
        int64_t mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF0000; //to remove 16 lsb bits
        int64_t x = (currentTime & mask) | get<0>(t);
        int64_t y = (currentTime & mask) | get<1>(t);
        /* 
             *  Normal case: where x is less than y
             *                     ____x____________y______ 
             *                     <--------0xffff-------->
             *
             *  abnormal case: where x is greater than y
             *                     ____y____________x______ 
             *                     <--------0xffff-------->
         *  In the abnormal case just subtract 0xffff - x) + y + 1 to get the duration by which y increased
            */
        if(x > y) {
            int64_t increase = (0xFFFF - x) + y + 1;
            return make_tuple(x, y + increase);
        }
        return make_tuple(x, y);
    }

    int main ()
    {
        srand (time(NULL));

        //generate the timestamp for SSL
        vector<tuple<int64_t, int64_t, int64_t, int64_t> > tracks;
        for (int i = 0; i < rand()%5; i++) {
            tracks.push_back(generateTimeStamp());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++)
            cout << hex << "generated tracks " << tracks[i] << endl;

        //generate the timestamp for window
        auto window = generateTimeStamp();
        cout << hex << "generated window " << window << endl;

        auto currentTimeStamp = getTimeStampCount();
        cout << hex << "current timestamp " << currentTimeStamp << endl;
        //make sure currentTimeStamp is greater than current window timestamps and the difference between them is not more than 16 bits(approximately 1 minute)
        for (int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
            if(currentTimeStamp <= get<3>(tracks[i]) || (get<2>(tracks[i]) - currentTimeStamp) >= 0xFFFF) {
                cout << "error " << "currentTimeStamp " << currentTimeStamp << "track " << tracks[i] << endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            if(currentTimeStamp <= get<3>(window) || (get<2>(window) - currentTimeStamp) >= 0xFFFF) {
                cout << "error " << "currentTimeStamp " << currentTimeStamp << "window " << window << endl;
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        //remapped tracks timestamps 
        std::vector<std::tuple<int64_t, int64_t>> remappedTracks;
        for (int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
            remappedTracks.push_back(remap(currentTimeStamp, tracks[i]));
        }

        //remapped window timestamps 
        auto remappedWindow = remap(currentTimeStamp, window);
        cout << "remapped window " << hex << remappedWindow << endl;

        //check if window timestamps overlap with tracks timestamps
        for (int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
            auto realTrackTimeStamps = make_tuple(get<2>(tracks[i]), get<3>(tracks[i]));
            auto realWindowTimeStamps = make_tuple(get<2>(window), get<3>(window));
            bool shouldBe = isOverlapping(realTrackTimeStamps, realWindowTimeStamps);
            bool got = isOverlapping(remappedTracks[i], remappedWindow);
            if (shouldBe != got) {
                cout << "generated track " << tracks[i] << endl;
                cout << "generated window " << window << endl;
                cout << "ramapped track " << remappedTracks[i] << endl;
                cout << "ramapped window " << remappedWindow << endl;
            }
            assert(shouldBe == got);
        }
    }
   ```

Code:https://ideone.com/cpUrHL to give some idea. This is simulated code to give perspective.

Any ideas to make it better or any bugs you can think of?

Note: Process_1 and 2 can't be modified to pass additional information and also the api's can't be changed at this point of time.